# How to find the route between two places in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, gps, maps, jsr179

How do I find the route information between two places in [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry)?

I'm using MapField to show the map in my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood, you need to get a path length between several locations.
It's not possible in MapField, you can only set that route by yourself.

### Invoke BB Maps for route direction

You can always use MapField in you application for simple functionality, like present locations, and use BlackBerry Maps application for enhanced stuff like select locations and route directions presentation for user.

To invoke BB Maps for route direction use code:

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MAPS,
                        new MapsArguments(
                        MapsArguments.ARG_LOCATION_DOCUMENT,document));
```

With document formed like:

```
<location-document>
     <GetRoute>
        <location lon='-8030000' lat='4326000' label='Kitchener, ON' description='Kitchener, Ontario, Canada' />
        <location lon='-7569792' lat='4542349' label='Ottawa, ON' description='Ottawa, Ontario, Canada' />
     </GetRoute>
</location-document>
```

Result will be like
[alt text http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecentersupport/kmsupport/supportknowledgebase/images/DB-00599_3.jpg](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecentersupport/kmsupport/supportknowledgebase/images/DB-00599_3.jpg)[alt text http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecentersupport/kmsupport/supportknowledgebase/images/DB-00599_4.jpg](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecentersupport/kmsupport/supportknowledgebase/images/DB-00599_4.jpg)

Now, in BlackBerry Maps you can register your App menu item and start or update your App with selected location using MapView.
See [How To - Add an ApplicationMenuItem to BlackBerry Maps](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/How_To_-_Add_an_ApplicationMenuItem_to_BlackBerry_Map.html?nodeid=1371852&vernum=0)

**UPDATE**

### Use the gmap navigation service for driving directions

See [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

Comment: Thanks Coldice,Can u pls tell me which method is good to develop Blackberry GPS application either MapField or BlackberryMap or some other map and Can u pls tell me what is the difference between MapField and Blackberry map.

Comment: Actually i have tried all Knowledge base documents and sample applications ya.Both map field and Blackberry map have their own merits and demerits so i don't know which is good for my application.Anyway thanks for ur help its help lot.

Comment: Well, I mean, you can use them both in same app. Youre welcome!