# How to draw a route between two geopoints on the Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, draw

I have two OverlayItem's on a MapView. How can I draw a route between the two geopoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This application is contained with source code... It'll solve ur probs.

http://www.anddev.org/the_friend_finder_-_mapactivity_using_gps_-_part_i_-_ii-t93.html

Answer (score 2):

This posting [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations) suggests:

> you must not use the Map Service with any applications for route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device

As such, there is no Android or Google API for showing the route between two points on Android, as far as I know.  People have hacked it in by various approaches, but you run the risk of having your Map key disabled.

If I am wrong, I would love to be corrected.

Comment: Your semi-wrong, you cant do turn by turn navigation like satnavs. But you can draw route between two points http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html
http://home.ameliemedia.com/android-app-aroundme/#tips