# How to display a route between two geocoords in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

I'm just writing an App for displaying the route between two coords (lat, long) in google maps view.
Displaying an single coord (even with a marker) works fine, but how to draw route between two point with 2 markers?

I must admit that I'm quite new to Android and the maps-API...

Comment: I am doing a similar kind of app and like to know if using kml or using the api to return a json is better.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

this is working example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685). check it out. it helps to create the route overlay on the map. here is the [complete source](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/src/org/ci/geo/route) code for that.

Comment: One note, you might be running afoul of the Google Maps api if you use it to obtain driving directions (they removed this capability from the android maps api).

Comment: yep. but we can do manipulations with the kml file of maps. in my answer, they are retriving the coordinates points to the route from the google maps kml file. check the RoadProvider.java the are build the url to get the road coordintes from the kml file.

Comment: Thank you, that's excactly the thing I was looking for :)
I think this will help for understanding and re-program it by myself.
Thanks again :)

Comment: @praveen i have completely followed your above link for route map but i got null null pointer exception mpointsize .also am getting fatal exception as well here i have posted all my source code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928933/the-questions-is-related-to-routemap-path-names-displaying please anyone help me out of this error am getting fatal and null pointer exception at drawpath() .and send me rectified code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Your route will be a list of points so you have to create a route overlay class.  And in the draw method of the overlay class you have to draw a Path between the points.

Comment: so true when it comes to offline maps too...