# Struggling to implement google directions api in Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions, map-directions

I would like to implement google walking/cycle directions into an Android app im creating but I'm struggling to get my head around how to do this. I've recognised that the most accepted way is to query google via http to retrieve a kml file, which is translated back into the android app. owever since I've been java/android programming for about a day Im just struggling abit! Is there anyone out there who can point me to a pretty comprehensive tutorial of how to achieve a simple A to B navigation app or even better send me a simple project for me to review, breakdown and adapt!

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You query is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643993/how-to-display-a-route-between-two-geocoords-in-google-maps-android

Answer (score 0):

Same has been discussed here:

[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

use the following code:

`Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);`