# drawing path on map in android

Tags: android, path, dictionary, direction, android-canvas

i need to draw a path between 2 points in my application.
but i couldn't find any simple example.is there anyone knows something about 
drawing path on map in android?can you help me...

Comment: do you want to show path between two location of map

Answer (score 0):

whatever you want is not clear to much. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643993/609765) question it might be helpful to you