# How to draw points into google maps on android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My problem is that i have a list of adresses and i must display a path from the first point to the last one passing throw all the other points like im going by car...
I don't the right name for that functionality so i couldn't search it on google...
Someone knows how can i do it? or the name of that functionality?
If you dont understand what im looking for is the functionality that google offers on maps.google.com where you can say where you are, and where are you going... Than google shows you a way to go by car, or walking or by bus... I need something like that and passing throw another points...

Answer (score 1):

Your question might be answered by another thread on plotting routes in google maps on android.

[How to display a route between two geocoords in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643993/how-to-display-a-route-between-two-geocoords-in-google-maps)

And

[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685)

Otherwise google somerhing like: 'android development google maps route'

/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

[LINK1](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html#ixzz0rfsIHaO2)

[LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

refer the above both links which a sample code of drawing routepath.