# Android Google Maps API v2 display route

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display a route between two geocoords in google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643993/how-to-display-a-route-between-two-geocoords-in-google-maps)

I am looking for a way to get the route between 2 points displayed in the Map using Google Maps API v2. I have searched in SO but I can't find an example for this. Maybe someone can help me with links or an example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643993/how-to-display-a-route-between-two-geocoords-in-google-maps

Comment: Just a commento: Google maps API V2 will become deprecated on May 2013. Google is sending mails to developers in order to migrate their mashups to a newer version.

Comment: @jap1968 You are talking about the JavaScript API, but my question is about the Android Google Maps API v2.

Comment: The answer from Waza_Be is the only way that will work. The API itself does not display routes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the v2 of the Maps API, a route is just a [PolyLine](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/mapview-tt/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline). IMHO is way more convenient/easy  to use than the old fashioned overlay.

From the [Google Maps API V2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines#geodesic_and_non-geodesic_lines):

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                   .add(new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298), 
                        new LatLng(-31.95285, 115.85734))
                   .geodesic(true));
```

Comment: I'm using the same code you used, but some times the lines don't follow the streets or avenues, do you have a solution?

Comment: The polyline doesn't have anything to do with streets or avenues. If they don't match, is because you are creating the polyline with the wrong coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The distance calculation is a method of the GLatLng object.

You can use something like this:

DISTANCE = markerOne.getPoint().distanceFrom(markerTwo.getPoint());

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Comment: Yeah, with that you can calculate the distance, but I'm looking for the route (group of points) between 2 coordinates.