# Android Google Directions Service usable natively? with wrapper framework? Public transit/biking directions available?

Tags: android, api, frameworks

Some questions about Android and Google Directions Service:

- Is there a native way on Android to use the Directions Service from Google or are there any nice Wrapper Frameworks? 
  I would like to retrieve the time needed to get from A to B and maybe show the route in a table and/or map.
- As far as I know directions can only be retrieved for "walking" and "driving". Is there a way (maybe not from google) to get this Information also for public transports or "biking" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this is what you want, but you could fire up an intent like this:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=some+address&daddr=another+Address"
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
```

To get biking directions add "&dirflg=b" to the url. For public transport add "dirflg=r".

This will display the route in the google Maps app. If you want to get this in your app inside a mapview, please see [this code at github](https://github.com/jansanz/DrivingDirsMapActivity). You could hack into the code to add biking and public transport functionality.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: If this answer satisfies you, you could mark your question as answered :) This is how StackOverflow works.
BTW here there is another way of doing this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685

Comment: Certainly helped me! And an alternative to saddr=some+address is saddr=[lat],[long] (e.g. saddr=51.2648524,-1.0877917). If you miss saddr altogether and specify only daddr, the directions will start from your current location.

Comment: home.ameliemedia.com is now a parked page with no content. What to do now?

Comment: I uploaded the source to github: https://github.com/janfsd/DrivingDirsMapActivity

Comment: @JanS. I removed the link to the parked page; please rollback if there's any reason to keep it.

Comment: Where did you find documentation for this?

Comment: There is nothing at http://www.github.com/janfsd/DrivingDirsMapActivity. Any way to get it?

Comment: @iturki I updated the link. Should be now https://github.com/jansanz/DrivingDirsMapActivity