# Android google.navigation Intent Modes?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I'm currently developing an application that will launch a navigation intent.  I know that this isn't an official API, but it works perfectly the way I want it to.

I allow the user to select driving, walking, and bus navigation to a location.  The intent to launch directly into Google Maps Navigation looks like this:

`google.navigation:ll=` + a latitude and longitude, then + `&mode=` then your mode of transportation.  For example, to navigate using walking directions to a certain area:

`google.navigation:ll=blah,blah&mode=w`

Driving is default, or `&mode=d`, and biking is `&mode=b`, but I can't figure out bus (public transit).

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Edit: So far, I've found that `mode=public` gives bike directions, `mode=transit` gives driving, frustratingly, `mode=bus` also returns bike directions.

More: `mode=train` also gives driving...  There's GOT to be a way to do this...

**Another Edit:** I realized just now that I'm pretty sure that it doesn't exist, because after experimenting with terms I realized that I should instead launch a Google Maps intent with a bus search, but does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It's a bit of a guessing game right now...

Comment: Only chance to have it is to try everything... Starting with "p"ublic or "t"ransport ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bunch of guessing and hunting around, I have decided that it is impossible to launch directly to bus navigation, because that would involve CHOOSING a bus for the person to ride, which wouldn't make sense.

Instead, you can launch them to a Google Maps search to the destination like so, thank you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853515/839947) to a similar question:

`"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=lat,long&dirflg=r"`

With the `&dirflag` specifying public transit.  (Why the "r" I have no idea...)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to append the [travel mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) as needed, with the travel modes listed below.

- *driving* (default) indicates standard driving directions using the road network.
- *walking* requests walking directions via pedestrian paths & sidewalks (where available).
- *bicycling* requests bicycling directions via bicycle paths & preferred streets (where available).
- *transit* requests directions via public transit routes (where available).

If you would like to launch an `Intent` and allow the user to select between Maps or Browser you can do it this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+ starting_point_lat+","+starting_point_long+"&daddr="+dest_point_lat+","+dest_point_long+"&mode=transit"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Public transportation is mode `r`, just use

```
google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=r
```

would do the trick, there is no need to launch an url first and wait for it to redirect to google map.