# Android Google Maps API v2 start navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have an app that displays a map with a marker.  When the user touches the marker I want to start navigation for them.

Is there an Intent/Activity that I can pass a longitude and latitude and start theusers navigation app?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255192/android-google-navigation-intent-modes

Answer (score 6):

I solved it like this. The url posted is similar.

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LAT,START_LON&daddr=END_LAT,END_LON"));
startActivity(navigation);
```

Where Start is the START_LON and START_LAT is the longitude and latitude and END_LON, END_LAT is the end

Comment: Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LON,START_LAT&daddr=END_LON,END_LAT"));
    
startActivity(navigation);

Comment: And the order should be LATITUDE, LONGITUDE instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

That works fine:

```
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cri = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(cri, true);

    Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    String latMy = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());
    String lngMy = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());

    Toast.makeText(this, "Navigation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + latMy + ","
            + lngMy + "&daddr=" + "18.7703500,19.4534500";

    Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    navigation.setData(Uri.parse(url));

    startActivity(navigation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+"18.7703500,19.4534500");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
```