# How to get direction navigation in Google maps in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to show navigation direction while clicking the info window.

I tried some code, it shows the **Preview** button, but it does not show the **navigation** button.

I got it like in the picture below: [image: Note Below Preview Icon]

But, I want it like this: [image]

Here my code:

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" +
            "saddr="+ gps.latitude + "," + gps.longitude + "&daddr=" + marker.getPosition().latitude + "," +
            marker.getPosition().longitude+ "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving"));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) on how to launch Google Maps navigation with turn-by-turn directions to the address or coordinate specified.

Here is a sample Intent which requests turn-by-turn navigation to Taronga Zoo, in Sydney Australia:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Check these related SO threads:

- [Is there an API for Google Maps navigation in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191825/is-there-an-api-for-google-maps-navigation-in-android)
- [Android Google Maps API v2 start navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027867/android-google-maps-api-v2-start-navigation)