# Can I launch an intent using only javascript in an Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, maps

I have a html page that shows the directions from the current location to a certain address.

I would like to do the same but use the map app instead of showing it in a browser.

When I use :

```
<script>
    document.location = "geo:0,0?q=myaddress";
</script>
```

That works fine but does not show me  the route.

What I read from this : [Android Google Directions Service usable natively? with wrapper framework? Public transit/biking directions available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853017/android-google-directions-service-usable-natively-with-wrapper-framework-publi)

It should be possible using this code :

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=some+address&daddr=another+Address"
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
```

Can I do the same just using javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is capable of detecting links to Google Maps in the browser and redirect the `Intent` to the native Google Maps app, if it is set as the default app. There is, however, no way to force the user to use the Google Maps app. Clicking the link can also show him the activity chooser or open Google Maps in the browser. It might also open a third-party app that is registered to handle the same `Intent`. The code snippet you posted will behave exactly like that, too.

This not only works from the browser, but with all links in the system. For example, I sent the link you posted via e-mail to myself and clicked it on my phone. I could open it with my Goolge Maps app. So there is really no need for JavaScript, you can just use a simple HTML link to send the `Intent`.

Comment: I disagree about JavaScript part, because sometimes you need to have a fallback if the application is not installed, so the user should be able to do required actions via the mobile version of the site.

Answer (score -1):

Just simply call the function from JavaScript to Android , and inside the function you can call the android intent.

you can find out the tutorial how to call android function from JavaScript:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html

and call the map using Google V3 library .

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3

Comment: The links provided only show how to make Java APIs available to JavaScript running in a WebView inside a custom Android application but the question is asking how to launch an intent from JavaScript running in a browser.  Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question.