# Google Maps algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps

how can I implement algorithms such as Dijkstra or backtracking on Google Maps integrated in Android ? For example I want to compute a route from city A to city B such that I pay the lowest price for gas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685). It has the Route finding Example. Google removes the Route finding api. But we have develop the code for the draw the route using `Overlay`. this is what done on that  working example.

Comment: we are developing that code with our OWN Logic from the available package. then Who want to authorize it? that example helps you for that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I asked that because of some posts from that link saying you can get blocked your google key for maps

Answer (score 1):

Since Google Maps doesn't provide access to the actual road data, I don't think it is possible to implement your own routing algorithm.

You could use road data from another source such as http://openstreetmap.org .

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example ?

Comment: The best would be to probably start here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing
There is a link to the Routing mailing list, where you can get more information. Also there is a new Stackoverflow-like help site for OSM: http://help.openstreetmap.org/