# Dijktra's Algorithm implementation in android

Tags: android, data-structures, dijkstra

I wanted to implement Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest distance between two nodes.

Comment: Even wikipedia lists the algorithm... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have integrated this Java implement to my android project:
https://github.com/stewbob/dijkstra

Answer (score 0):

This question has asked already if your question is different then provide more information
[Google Maps algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281334/google-maps-algorithm)

Otherwise You can do like this.

Several algorithms have so far been introduced to
find out the shortest path in a network. Though none of
the algorithms can be considered as the best in all the
situations, Dijkstra's algorithm is the fastest known
single-source shortest-path algorithm for arbitrary
directed graphs with unbounded nonnegative weights.
This algorithm is often used in routing. This algorithm
when implemented in android and supported by proper
GUI can produce a simple yet powerful application
which can be used by marketing executives, tourists or
city newbies etc. In today’s world where we are falling
short of fuel, knowing shortest path is useful. Public
transport can also be modeled as a graph: every station
is represented by a node and an edge exists if there is a
line directly connecting two station. Here I have used a
college premises for experimentation.

In another activity Google map is displayed and the
current location of the device is also shown. All the
nodes on the geographical area are numbered using
canvas.drawText and the shortest path is drawn using
canvas.drawPath. One of the class contains all the code
to create and upgrade the SQLite database and the code
to open and close the database and to insert and delete
and retrieve and update the records. All the nodes
visited so far by the marketing executive can be viewed
on Google map and SMSed to his authority or anyone
by adding contact from the phonebook. The application
can connect with web server. In case the executive do
not know the next place to be visited, he sends a request
to the server to supply him with the necessary
information. The web servers is made in asp.net. The
database used there is Ms Access.

If this application is being used by marketing
executives, then all of them are connected to their
marketing company’s web server where they inquire
about their next location to visit. SQLite stores the all
the nodes visited so far. As per the developer’s guide
“SQLite is a powerful and lightweight relational
database engine available to all applications”.