# Map Routing - For Android 1.5 and Blackberry 5.0

Tags: android, blackberry

How to make the Map routing in the Android 1.5 sdk.

Is the Map routing available for the Android 1.5?
Is the Map routing available for the Blackberry 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this discussion for google map routing

[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

for Blackberry maps see this article

[Display and clear a route on a map by using a location document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_determining_a_route_using_getRoute_893347_11.jsp)