# How can I highligh roads in android gps

Tags: android, gps, maps

I'm trying my strength in developing an application in android and I have the following question:

My android device comes with a built in google map (oddly enough it's called maps). I'd like to develop on top of that platform. The requirements are:

- Querying the map for points based on names of streets I give (and numbers perhaps)
- Highlighting lines or roads drawn between the highlighted points I gave

Does android's map support it? If not, is there any platform (free or commercial) that will make such a thing possible?

Thank you very much~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read basic [Google Maps tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). For transforming street names to geo-locations and back use [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).
2. AFAIK there is no route calculation functionality in Google Maps for Android. Furthermore, live route calculations for navigation are not allowed by [Google Maps terms of service](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-tos.pdf), article 8.7.

   For alternative approach take a look at: [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)