# finding route directions from source to destinaton in android

Tags: android, google-maps, draw, directions

I am new to android, i have managed to write code that displays the google map, i can able to give source and destination addresses and place push pin over there using reverse Geocode concept...

the scenario is i want to display the driving,walking,bicycling directions from source to destination point with displaying a line from source to destination..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no route calculation functionality in Google Maps for Android. Furthermore, live route calculations for navigation are not allowed by [Google Maps terms of service](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-tos.pdf), article 8.7.

For alternative approach take a look at: [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)