# Driving route from my location to multiple destination in Google Maps Android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, driving-directions

can you help me how to draw a driving route from my location ( current location ) to a some locations which we manually enter in the program, so when we taped a marked location, a driving route will be drawn from my current location to the marked location, but the marked location not just one,
this some of my locations :

LatLng(5.175783,97.140950);

LatLng(5.172767,97.131161);

LatLng(5.163928,97.136822);

LatLng(5.180353,97.122297);

The below tutorial i have followed.

[Driving route from my location to destination in Google Maps Android API V2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/#comment-65604)

Comment: @Muahammad What have you tried post here and did this tutorial not help you?

Comment: @patrik This tutorial is very helpful, I am just confused about where to put a multiple dastination

Comment: @ Muhammad Agessy Barazi so you want to draw routes from your location to multiple destinations?

Comment: you need to draw a route path from source to destination point with some pin points in that path right?

Comment: @Muhammad Agessy Barazi you should give more clear idea so that developers can help you.

Comment: @kalai.g yes, thats right, but i'm confused how to put thw destination point in the program :(

Comment: @patik where the less obvious??

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of samples in google where you can surf through.

check following links ,you may get an idea

[finding route directions from source to destinaton in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836468/finding-route-directions-from-source-to-destinaton-in-android)

[Showing a route between two points with multiple waypoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039647/showing-a-route-between-two-points-with-multiple-waypoints)

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

http://dhavaltshah2012.blogspot.in/2012/04/source-to-destination-path-in-map.html

[how to Draw train route map between source and destination in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500051/how-to-draw-train-route-map-between-source-and-destination-in-android)

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/