# Direction Route From User Location to Marker Using String Builder on MarkerClick

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, stringbuilder

What I want to do is just show driving routes to my Fragment Map when the Marker is Clicked.

This [Tutorial](http://cariprogram.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-googlemap-v2-direction-route-dari-klik-marker-ke-lokasi-gps-mylocation.html) is my source.

Right now the route only shows on OTHER app not in the `myactivity` layout. What I want to do is show the driving direction route in my fragment

Here is my `MainActivity.Class`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private LatLng Mark_Kantor_Gubernur = new LatLng(-0.9376155, 100.3600001);
private LatLng Mark_Bappeda_prov_Sumbar = new LatLng(-0.913884, 100.359176);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Getting Map From Google
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

    //Getting Location Based on Fused Location(GPS & Network)
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Handle map when opened on first time
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));


    //Setting UP Marker
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Mark_Kantor_Gubernur)
                                           .title("Kantor Gubernur")
                                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_cp)));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Mark_Bappeda_prov_Sumbar)
                                           .title("Kantor Bappeda SUMBAR")
                                           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                           .fromResource(R.drawable.marker_cp)));

    TextView locationTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLatLongLocation);
    locationTV.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ",Longitude:" + longitude);

    //Setting onclick marker & Direction to Marker
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    //you can handle marker click from here


    try {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String daddr = (String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude)+","+String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().longitude));

        stringBuilder.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");

        stringBuilder.append("&saddr="+String.valueOf(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude())+","
                +String.valueOf(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude()));

        stringBuilder.append("&daddr="+daddr);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(stringBuilder.toString()));
        startActivity(intent);

    }catch (Exception ee)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lokasi Saat Ini Belum Didapatkan, Coba Nyalakan GPS, Keluar Ruangan dan Tunggu Beberapa Saat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    return false;
}
```

I have looked at [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - Driving directions, Route Between Two Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685), [Draw Route On Google Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089351/to-draw-route-on-google-maps-android) but this is showing just straight lines between the users location and destination, what I want is driving route.

If I add this polyline code:

```
Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude()),new LatLng(marker.getPosition().latitude, marker.getPosition().longitude)).width(2).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));
```

It just shows straight lines in a Google map fragment

Note: Please include comments and an explanation on answer code, I'm very new in android and still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Selector elements should be placed in res\drawable.  Right click on 'drawable', select 'new' then select 'Drawable resource file'.  Name the file and you should be good to go.