# Android - Google Maps show route

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

I am implemented Google Maps in my application, and it shows my position with blinking dot. Now if I add there point on specific coordinates, Can I draw route between them to visually show, what the route betweem them should be or it is specific funcionality of Google Maps I am not able to use?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this was the discussion that i found best and it worked for me in my application

[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685)

Comment: Thanks, but there is so many files it needs to be inserted?

Comment: Yes. You will find a complete source code link there. You just have to analyze the source code and customize it according to your need.

Comment: But for my app, it is intended for pure business use, and if there is API policy by Google, that this is not permited,I think I won't be able to use it, I am afraid

Comment: Sorry i dont have information about that. But you can ask other good developers here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android-help..I answered what you questioned. For the above comment i dont know sorry.

Comment: The above example doesn't work for http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=Vaxjo,Sweden&daddr=Stockholm,Sweden&ie=UTF8&Zoom=0&output=kml or either by using lat,long of source and destination address.