# Launch Google Maps to show road directions

Tags: android, adt

How do I launch Google Maps from my own application to show road directions from current position (GPS) to a specified address?

Comment: Do you want to use the Maps from Google Maps or do you really want to launch Google Maps on your Mobile device and quit your application?

Comment: This is what you looking for i think : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685

Comment: I want to launch google maps (and quit my app). I could still use the back button to get back to my app, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This intent should launch the appropriate Maps Activity with the directions input screen populated with current location and a destination point:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=51.448,-0.972"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
    "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Jeff, I was wondering if the parser would handle the `&output=kml` parameter? I'm interested in displaying a route with some placemarks that's actually published online as a public map.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:40.763500,-73.979305");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

For more information:

// Map point based on address

```
Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+California");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);
```

// Or map point based on latitude/longitude like the answer of @wegginho

`Uri location = Uri.parse("geo:37.422219,-122.08364?z=14"); // z param is zoom level`