# Constraints and restrictions in using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps

I have developed an android mobile application

I am using Google Maps API for

1. Displaying Current Location (Drawaing different types of shapes on my current location)
2. Displaying Nearby Areas. However the positions come from my local database and i am just overlaying it on my map
3. Displaying routes between two positions. Infact i want to draw many routes from my current positions. I have reffered [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685) for displaying routes between two positions.
4. Displaying all the Nearby Areas in a ListView

My questions is : what i am doing here is considered as legal or not ?

I want to know what are the rules for using Google Maps ?

Or lets say what are the things that we can do with google maps that would be considered as legal.

Is there any license scheme for using Google Maps ? or its for Free ?

Please guide me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirements are perfectly legal, You may have a look at the following link http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Google maps is free if you are below the the query limit
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits