# How to open google get direction in mapview?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-mapview

Am creating android app to get directions between source and destination(like in google map- getDirection) Addresses as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=12.84281852,80.22529753&daddr=13.00355419,80.200881958"));
              startActivity(intent);
```

But my source and destination address will often change.So i cannot use startActivity every time when location changes.

So can anyone suggest me how to implement this, without using startActivity or how to do display the resulting map in mapview. so that the mapview will show the direction between source and dest. Address and the mapview should be updated when the parameter changes.

How to do this so my map view will have driving directions?

Comment: **[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070968/google-maps-api-directions/10425721#10425721)** are all the details for getting directions in google map.