# "Google Map" how to indicate the Way(Road that lead's) from current location to the destination

Tags: android, google-maps

I didn't find the appropriate way to indicate or mark between the two location in Google  map so, u'r help will be appriciated... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution on Stackoverflow: [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685)