# cannot draw path on Android GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using the algorithm provided here
[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)
for drawing a route on the map.
But some times, even if i have all the point to be drawn, the path displayed on the map isn't complete.

Can somebody tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "isn't complete"? Not all path points are drawn? or?

Comment: exactly...it is drawn only a part of the route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finnally I found the answer: on the KML file tag "coordinates" apears more that once  when the route is a long one. The alghoritm uses an array to store coordinates, that is initialized every time the tag coordinates apear in the KML file. All you have to do is to store cordinates in an ArrayList.