# Android Google map routing help

Tags: android

I am developing a Android Google map app using Google 2.3 API. I googled around and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations?answertab=active#tab-top) But while testing the application i got exception. Here's is the full stack-trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.som.routing/com.som.routing.GmaproutingtryActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.som.routing.GmaproutingtryActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.som.routing-2.apk]
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.som.routing.GmaproutingtryActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.som.routing-2.apk]
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
09-05 16:16:05.914: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(405):     ... 11 more
```

Anyone gone this example please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Android could not find class `com.som.routing.GmaproutingtryActivity`. Did you include it (or the lib) in your project?

Comment: Yes. I have only one activity used in my app. As its the only activity so it should be called first. I checked the manifest as well.. Its ok

Comment: Did you register it in your AndroidManifest.xml? Can you post the contents of this file?

Comment: Yes i register that Acivity. Here's Manifest please check it out

Comment: `code`<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".GmaproutingtryActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </activity> `code`

Comment: You should have package defined in top level manifest element: `<manifest package="..">`. What does it contain in your case?

Comment: Problem fixed. You were Its just had some problem in Manifest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

give the permission in the manifest file like this
`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`. In the manifest tag of the manifest file declare and define the **package** attribute .If the problem still continues uninstall the apk and reinstall you application.