# BlackBerry Map Issue

Tags: blackberry, maps, blackberry-maps

based on the instructions [How To Route Between two location in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

I tried this example for blackberry and get the result (distance between the two locations correctly as described in the example).

but after running the code I can se the road but I can't see the map behind the road

this is the pic describe my problem

[image: map doesn't appears while the road appear]

so what is the problem? cause I face this problem in each map application i test it.

Comment: have you tried latitude longitude values in example.

Comment: the example contain the latitude and longitude ( use them to get the distance and draw the line )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on a real device?  My experience has shown that the OS5 simulators are extremely unreliable in their ability to download/display maps.  You could also try an OS6 simulator -- I have had much better luck with those.

Comment: is your device properly provisioned with a data package from a cell provider?  I have also had trouble when either no SIM is inserted, or when an unlocked device is brought onto a different carrier's network.

Comment: yes , my device provisioned with a data package from a cell provider