# How can i get the nearest location by using google map api in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a application based on location based services.I need to find the nearest locations like Restaurants,Hospitals,Companies. I find we can use google map api services.
I tried to find the way using this service provide by google

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/
```

But i did not get any result please suggest me how can we get the nearest location details.
Provide me is there any samples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-using-google-maps-api-in-android/8428414#8428414

Comment: Yes is got it.But what is the sensor perimeter in the service link

Comment: its a boolean parameter to keep true or false.

Answer (score 1):

use this as as URL:

```
http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=hospitals+near+<<coordiantes>>
```

coordinates = 12.545454,78.434304 (just an example).

you will get the coordinates through your location service.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Yes it is showing the map but i want nearest co ordinates.

Comment: you can get the address and use reverse geo-coding to get the geo co-ordinates

Comment: Thank you.We can use this service to get geo points data directly. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere