# how to get the name entered by the user and search that respective location in edittext

Tags: android, google-maps

i can place Google map in my android mobile. i put search option for google map. if the user give the location and click button search means it find the location in google map. now i want display relative location when the user give the location name in Edittext..Please give me any reference.....

```
   i try this code of button click
     if (v == search) {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocationName(location
                    .getText().toString(), 5);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0)
                        .getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (addresses.get(0)
                        .getLongitude() * 1E6));

                controller.animateTo(p);
                controller.setZoom(12);
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(getApplicationContext(),p);
                List<Overlay> lisOverlays = view.getOverlays();
                lisOverlays.clear();
                lisOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

            }
```

the button search click means it shows location also . i want displays the locations according to user search in edit text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-using-google-maps-api-in-android/8428414#8428414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to accept input from user and search place on map.

```
          String value = editText1.getText().toString();
          // Do something with value!
          Log.d("value", value);

          Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                    value, 5);
                String add = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    p = new GeoPoint(
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                            (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
                    mc.animateTo(p);    
                    mapView.invalidate();
                }    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Some changes required

Comment: i try ur code it cannot shows relative location while entering edittext

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:hint="Search Location">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>