# Android : to show google map on the location enterd by user

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the name entered by the user and search that respective location in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208985/how-to-get-the-name-entered-by-the-user-and-search-that-respective-location-in-e)

I have actually written a code for showing google maps as per user in android. The user enters location in edit text which i have used in JSON for fetching latitude and longitude and have pointed the map to that latitude and longitude. Now the problem i am facing is i have stored the location dat user enters in a variable named location and i have passed dat variable in JSON. But whenever i run the program and enter whatso ever location, map is being pointed near Hyderabad.
I have implemented this code in a tabview
Here is my code...

the basic prob here is the latitude and longitude from json are not being passed to other page...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

        Et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt); 
        Bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search);
        location = Et.getText().toString();
       final String readTwitterFeed = readTwi("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=+location+&sensor=false");
       Bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {
           String strUrl,lon;
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               try
                {           

                    JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(readTwitterFeed).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

                    strUrl=jsonObject.getString("lat");
                    lon=jsonObject.getString("lng");
                    Log.i("location",strUrl);
                    Log.i("longtin",lon);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               Intent intent=new Intent(MapView.this,MapsActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("lat",strUrl);
               intent.putExtra("lng",lon);
               startActivity(intent);
           }

        });
  }
private String readTwi(String url)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
      if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          builder.append(line);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(MapView.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
      }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```