# Find the nearest location in google maps for android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there a way to find the nearest location in Google map according to a specific point ( Long/lat),
i read some thing about Google Place API, but i did not realize how to use it..
And is it possible to find the next nearest one too???

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) you could perform a [Places Search Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) where `location` is the users lat,lng:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&types=food&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Make sure you specify the `rankby=distance` parameter instead of the `radius` parameter if you wish to obtain the closest places in chronological order instead of the most prominent places in the specified radius.

I have also specified a `types=food` parameter in the request above to only return food type places in my response. Additional supported types can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/supported_types).

To use the [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) you will need to follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication) to obtain an API Key to use the service, this key will need to be sent with your request under the `key=AddYourKeyHere` parameter.

If you are looking to use this service in a JavaScript application, check out the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of the [Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Answer (score 2):

HERE IS THE WAY YOU CAN ACHIEVE IT

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Double l1 = location.getLatitude();
            Double l2 = location.getLongitude();
            address = GetAddress(l1, l2);               
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);  

private String GetAddress(Double lat, Double lon) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
    String ret = "";
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        if (!addresses.equals(null)) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress
                        .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                "\n");
            }
            ret = "Around: " + strReturnedAddress.toString();
        } else {
            ret = "No Address returned!";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = "Location: https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=" + lat
                + "," + lon;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = lat + "," + lon;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And also add these permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score -1):

[Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

Url::

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Need to change lat,long, radius, types, name and key.

**Note::** Need to Sign up for the developer preview.

Comment: for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl

Comment: The developer preview no longer exists.