# Find Location on Google Maps using coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a location on a map based on latitude and longitude coordinates. When I press a button I want to send the coordinates to Google Maps (or other app) and pinpoint that location. Any ideas of how I can achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by finding location? You want to animate to a certain location?

Comment: search in google maps for "32.297581,-64.775734"

Comment: want to know the location name or showing marker on that location??

Comment: This is a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428414/469983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a simple solution. I start the google maps app via an intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + serviceActivity.Latitude.toString() + "," + serviceActivity.Longitude.toString()));
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the nice example:

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/google-maps-on-android-android.html

Hope this will helps you..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate to a specific point on a google map you need to define a MapView. Then create a MapController and animate to a specific GeoPoint:

```
MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

double lat = latitude * 1e6;
double lon = longitude * 1e6;

GeoPoint startpoint = new GeoPoint((int) lat, (int) lon);
mapController.animateTo(startpoint);
```

Try this tutorial :[MapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview)