# finding nearby restaurants google maps api V2

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-places-api

I am new to android and I am trying to make an app that finds nearby restaurants and display them on the map. I've implemented the map already but I don't know how to find the nearby restaurants. I can retreive my own location although. Could someone provide me with some source code please?

Comment: I've been browsing through it for hours but I don't know how to start from there :/ ...

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl Hope this helps you on your way!