# Android: Finding nearby places with Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to get list of the nearby places using Google Places API. I have enabled requried API from Google Devloper Console and have an valid API key. I am able to get my corrent location. After I got the my current location I am trying to get nearby places list but it returns empty.

I have also tried giving `null` `PlaceFilter` but it gives same result.

```
private class MyGoogleMapOnMyLocationListener implements
            OnMyLocationChangeListener,
            ConnectionCallbacks,
            OnConnectionFailedListener {
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            if (!hasLastLocation) {
                hasLastLocation = true;
                mLastLocation = location;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location: " + location.toString());

                if (googleMap != null ) {
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.0f));

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                                .Builder(getActivity())
                                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .build();
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Google Api Client connected.");

            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting nearby places...");

                PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result =
                        Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got results: " + likelyPlaces.getCount() + " place found.");

                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                        }

                        likelyPlaces.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }
    }
```

Here is my [AndroidManifest.xml](http://pastebin.com/fkN0JJmx)

Here is my map [Fragment](http://pastebin.com/Ww0S1Aed)

I have followed indtructions from [Google Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/)

And I have tried accepted answer of this question:
[Show Current Location and Nearby Places and Route between two places using Google Maps API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl)

---

### UPDATE

I have enabled other map related APIs from Google Developer Console and it worked.

Comment: In my project I'm not able to recognize Places.GEO_DATA_API and similar Places.*.  Any suggestion which lib I;m missing!

Comment: Do you have Places API?

Comment: How can I confirm that, I have added ..gms:play-service:6.5.87 this as of now.

Comment: Add this to your gradle `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'`

Comment: https://github.com/pchauhan/GooglePlaceLib

Comment: If someone still has troubles with Places.GEO_DATA_API and similar Places.* - please use:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
instead of play-services-location.

Answer (score 2):

you may reffer given code and full [Demo](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    // Google API Key
    private static final String API_KEY = "<Your KEY>";

    // Google Places serach url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_TEXT_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;

        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @param refrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Details", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This is an answer for the REST API. The asker is looking for the use case for the Android API.