# Google Place SDK gives wrong current place detail

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places

In my application, I have a requirement where I need to track the user's current place and notify the user if he/she stays for some time.
So to do this, I am using Google's place SDK to get current place detail, [reference link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place) 
But the problem is output.

If I use Location service with priority **PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY** or **PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY**, the output of Place SDK is different for the same location.

My Location Request is as below:

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 
// or
// mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
```

As mentioned in above link, we don't have any option to pass current latitude-longitude, as SDK itself manage it.

So can anyone help me how I can get much accurate output from Place SDK.

Sample code of [background service](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/9tLMqiPU)

Comment: can't you retrieve the position as LatLng and check that the user stays in a given radius instead of using Places API ?

Comment: In my project,  where I need to use place details such as Place ID, name, address etc..

Comment: Exactly, where you need to use place details you'll use place details. But here it is not the best solution and you should just check how the position changes over time

Answer (score 0):

as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/googleapi-migration) states, you probably should migrate to `GoogleApi Client`

while the two different results returned, should have a different `PlaceLikelihood`.

as a matter of fact, the less precise the requested location is, the less accure the returned places are.

for the [LocationRequest](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest), there isn't even a `PRIORITY_BALANCED`, but only a `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` constant available - and the request interval will be automatically throttled when this is set, no matter what you try to set as the interval.

also see the [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient).

Comment: I have used FusedLocationProviderClient for location update.

Comment: @Mehta try logging the returned location, because the Places API (or GoogleApi Client) will show different results, because two different locations are being requested. "block level" accuracy is not really a GPS fix. it might depend where one requests it - sometimes the results might even be quite similar. the output will always depend on the input.

Comment: true. but in Place SDK, we don't have any provision to pass current Latitude- Longitude. PlaceDetectionClient itself fire a request to get the current location to the device and after getting current location, it will give a list of places

Comment: @Mehta the API would feature "Nearby Search", which permits lookup by coordinates - with the Places SDK, you don't have the option to do so (even if this might appear questionable). see this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035938/549372

Comment: Let me try this nearby search API