# Set Multiple Markers to inbuilt Maps app from my app

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm developing an app where i want to show the nearest locations (Stored in DB) to the user.

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=18.344,73.34");
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have tried this, and it works fine to show the single marker on the map, but my problem is that,
 "I want to show multiple markers.."
Is this allowed..?? if yes, please show me the way..?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl

Comment: thanks for the link, but i don't want to use google API, i want to use inbuilt MAPs Application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot over internet, finally i've learned few things.

1. For some reasons, Google don't allow developers to add multiple markers at the Google Maps App.
2. Using a hack of "source, destination and mid-places", you can achieve this to some extend. But then, all your markers won't be the same.

So, for better visuals, include Google Maps in your application and play with them.