# Nearby locations based Geo locations in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

There are 10 Geo locations(longitude&latitude),Markers should be pointed based on the distance between my current location to the first nearest  Geo location, From that Geo location to the next nearby location and vise versa.For this particular scenario will any Google map API support or shall we need  write own algorithm. If any please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure if google map API has something for this but you can always use the good old https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428414/5995040

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="#1baec3"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="33.8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="13.5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/search" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_margin_20"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_gray" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_toggle"
                android:layout_width="8.5dp"
                android:layout_height="8.5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_toggle"
                android:tint="@color/text_color"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_search_directory_near"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_toggle"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_margin_5"
                android:text="@string/near"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textColor="#797979"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly_map_radius"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11.5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_search_directory_near"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_radius_black_line"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10.3dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="9.8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
                    android:tint="#797979"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_map_radius"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8.8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                    android:text="@string/spinner_radius"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:textColor="#797979"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ly_map_country"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10.8dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ly_map_radius"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_radius_black_line"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="10.3dp"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="9.8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
                    android:tint="#797979"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_map_country"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6.3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_margin_7"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_margin_15"
                    android:text="@string/spinner_country"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:textColor="#1baec3"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



public class Map_Fragment extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener{
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng markerLocation;
    Projection projection;
    Point screenPosition;

    private static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.952854, 115.857342);
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689);
    private static final LatLng BRISBANE = new LatLng(-27.47093, 153.0235);

    private Marker mPerth;
    private Marker mSydney;
    private Marker mBrisbane;

    LinearLayout ly_map_radius, ly_map_country;
    TextView tv_map_radius, tv_map_country;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        ly_map_radius = root.findViewById(R.id.ly_map_radius);
        ly_map_country = root.findViewById(R.id.ly_map_country);

        tv_map_radius = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_map_radius);
        tv_map_country = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_map_country);

        return root;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ly_map_radius.setOnClickListener(this);
        ly_map_country.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        projection = mMap.getProjection();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(PERTH)
                .title("Perth")
                .snippet("Population: Perth")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

        mSydney = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(SYDNEY)
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("Population: Sydney")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        mSydney.showInfoWindow();

        mBrisbane = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(BRISBANE)
                .title("Brisbane")
                .snippet("Population: Brisbane")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        mBrisbane.showInfoWindow();

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.ly_map_country:
                builder.setTitle("Select Country");
                builder.setItems(countries, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        tv_map_country.setText(countries[which]);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.ly_map_radius:
                builder.setTitle("Select Radius");
                builder.setItems(radius, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        tv_map_radius.setText(radius[which] + " km radius");
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to offer some explanation of what’s going on here. It’s not especially useful to just dump a large block of code and expect others to sort through it.