# Getting places (shops) visited by the person using Google Places API from an Android

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I have to build a small App with Android Studio. I have to list places (shops) visited by the person using Google Places API. It's possible? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's something possible.

For the how, I think you best luck with this is to go read on the uses of Google Places API. All the links can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428209/show-current-location-and-nearby-places-and-route-between-two-places-using-googl)