# How to calculate REAL distance between two geopoints?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

I want to calculate distance between two geopoints in android. I used `Location.distanceTo` and `Location.distanceBetween` but this method return DIRECT length between two points. 
I want to calculate the route between two points and then calculate the total distance between all route points.

I don't want to show points or route on map. I just want to calculate the distance from current location to given points nothings else.

ie. I want to calculate the Route length between two geo points.
Can anyone help me to calculate the route length between two geo points?

Comment: do you want to use inbuilt Google map ?

Comment: The most "real" distance I can think of *is* the direct or great circle distance. A route is very conditional (car vs. pedestrian, avoid toll routes, avoid ferries, speed vs. distance travelled and so on)

Comment: I want the length of shortest route/Fastest route.

Comment: I found my answer I used this Google api and this will return all the data about route.

API : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=ORIGIN&destinations=DESTINATION&mode=bicycling&sensor=false

thank you all for your support.

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles.

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer I used this Google api and this will return all the data about route.

API : [Google Api for Route Calculation](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Ahmedabad&destination=Jodhpur&sensor=false)

You can find more info on [Google Map Api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns distance:

```
public double distance(float latA,float longA,float latB,float longB){
        double d2r = Math.PI / 180;



            double dlong = (longA - longB) * d2r;
            double dlat = (latA - latB) * d2r;
            double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2)
                    + Math.cos(latB * d2r) * Math.cos(latA * d2r)
                    * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
            double d = 6367 * c;

            return d;



}
```

But this is to find out displacement. And no idea about how to calculate distance between all route points. May be you can use this method and loop it.

Comment: This will return direct distance..I want the length of the route.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2023685/571353) from a similar question

```
public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {    
 LinearLayout linearLayout;
 MapView mapView;
 private Road mRoad;    
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);    
  new Thread() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    double fromLat = 49.85, fromLon = 24.016667; 
    double toLat = 50.45, toLon = 30.523333;
    String url = RoadProvider
      .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
    InputStream is = getConnection(url);
    mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
   }
  }.start();
 }

 Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
   textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
   MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
   List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
   listOfOverlays.clear();
   listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
   mapView.invalidate();
  };
 };

 private InputStream getConnection(String url) {
  InputStream is = null;
  try {
   URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
   is = conn.getInputStream();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return is;
 }    
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: bro... how can i use this and calculate the distance?

Comment: @Loshi you can have a look at this: https://developers.google.com/maps/