# To show the route by clicking between two points on Google map in Blackberry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, java-me

I am using JavaScript code to show the multiple pin points on Google Maps using Brownfield.  I set the first clicked point as the center point, and when the user clicks on any other point (which is not the center point) I want to display a route mapped from the center point to that clicked point.

I would appreciate help of any sort, including ideas besides using JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

Answer (score 1):

Google has a number of services available to people who program using their Maps. Go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference and check out the directions services. I'm not very familiar with them, but I'm guessing it's similar to their other services. You make a directions request object supplied with point a and point b, and it will send a message to Google asking for the appropriate directions, which will be returned in some sort of result object that you can use to show the way. Update point b each time the user clicks and resend the google request, and it should update the path. Check out the API and it shouldn't be too hard to get it working. As for alternatives to javascript, Google Maps is written all in javascript, so there really is no other way. But I know from experience, most of their supplied code works really well, so I bet you can get it working!

Answer (score 1):

Following link will show the route between two points:

[J2ME/Android/BlackBerry - driving directions, route between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685)