# Accurate paths on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a complicated problem with google maps.I am using android and i draw a path between 2 specific points but the problem is that the path is not accurate because it draw on reversible streets so the path now is not right can anyone have any idea how to ignore the wrong streets??

Comment: I tried this code but i got an exception 04-22 14:36:31.349: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:36:31.349: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ee.xx.ss/ee.xx.ss.RoadProvider}: java.lang.ClassCastException: ee.xx.ss.RoadProvider
04-22 14:36:31.349: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585).I think it's in the xml parser.
And i have another question did i need to have a layout for class RoadProvider or not??..

Comment: I tried the code that Pavan gives it to me.. In this class public static String getUrl(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat,
                  double toLon)..which values i need to pass to it?

Comment: @Agarwal yeah can you share it please because i had problems with other project.

Comment: i had created a jar file to drawroute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685). check it out. it helps to create the route overlay on the map. here is the [complete source code](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/src/org/ci/geo/route) for that.

**EDIT:**
as AlexAndro mentions below: "This method, using kml seems that is not available any more, this issue has been discussed on Stackoverflow in the last days. [Google Maps output=kml broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken) "

Comment: This method, using `kml` seems that is not available any more, this issue has been discussed on Stackoverflow in the last days. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken`

Comment: @AlexAndro Thank you for letting us know. I'll edit the answer with your post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below class code::

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;



public class RoutePath extends MapActivity { 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

    MapView mapView;
    private RoutePath _activity;

    GeoPoint srcGeoPoint,destGeoPoint;
    private static List<Overlay> mOverlays;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        _activity = this;

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); 


        double src_lat = SRCLAT;
        double src_long = SRCLNG;
        double dest_lat = DESTLAT;
        double dest_long = DESTLNG;
        srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),(int) (src_long * 1E6)); 
        destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),(int) (dest_long * 1E6)); 

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable srcdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_green);
        CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, this);
        OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");

        Drawable destdrawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_red);
        CustomItemizedOverlay destitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(destdrawable, this);
        OverlayItem destoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(destGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is dest Location.");

        srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
        destitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destoverlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(srcitemizedOverlay);
        mapOverlays.add(destitemizedOverlay);

        connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
        _connectAsyncTask.execute();         
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
        mOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint); 
        mapView.getController().setZoom(12); 
    } 


    @Override 
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        return false; 
    } 

    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            SHOW YOU PROGRESS BAR HERE
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fetchData();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);            
            if(doc!=null){
                Overlay ol = new MyOverLay(_activity,srcGeoPoint,srcGeoPoint,1);
                mOverlays.add(ol);
                NodeList _nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
                Node node1 = _nodelist.item(0);
                String _status1  = node1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                if(_status1.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                    NodeList _nodelist_path = doc.getElementsByTagName("overview_polyline");
                    Node node_path = _nodelist_path.item(0);
                    Element _status_path = (Element)node_path;
                    NodeList _nodelist_destination_path = _status_path.getElementsByTagName("points");
                    Node _nodelist_dest = _nodelist_destination_path.item(0);
                    String _path  = _nodelist_dest.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    List<GeoPoint> _geopoints = decodePoly(_path);
                    GeoPoint gp1; 
                    GeoPoint gp2; 
                    gp2 = _geopoints.get(0);
                    for(int i=1;i<_geopoints.size();i++) // the last one would be crash 
                    { 

                        gp1 = gp2;
                        gp2 = _geopoints.get(i);
                        Overlay ol1 = new MyOverLay(gp1,gp2,2,Color.BLUE);
                        mOverlays.add(ol1);
                    } 
                    Overlay ol2 = new MyOverLay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                    mOverlays.add(ol2);

                    DISMISS PROGRESS BAR HERE

                }else{
                     showAlert AS "Unable to find the route"
                }

                Overlay ol2 = new MyOverLay(_activity,destGeoPoint,destGeoPoint,3);
                mOverlays.add(ol2);
                DISMISS PROGRESS BAR HERE
            }else{
                showAlert AS "Unable to find the route"
            }

        }

    }
    Document doc = null;
    private void fetchData()
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append(","); 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)srcGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append("&destination=");//to 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append(","); 
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)destGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 )); 
        urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving"); 
        if(Constants.LOG)Log.d("xxx","URL="+urlString.toString());          
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null; 
        URL url = null; 
        try 
        { 
            url = new URL(urlString.toString()); 
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true); 
            urlConnection.connect(); 
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = (Document) db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());//Util.XMLfromString(response);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }catch (IOException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private List<GeoPoint> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<GeoPoint> poly = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (((double) lat / 1E5) * 1E6),
                    (int) (((double) lng / 1E5) * 1E6));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

CustomItemizedOverlay.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private final ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Context context;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

MyOverLay.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class MyOverLay extends Overlay 
{ 
    private GeoPoint gp1; 
    private GeoPoint gp2; 
    //private int mRadius=6; 
    private int mode=0; 
    private int defaultColor; 
    private String text=""; 
    private Bitmap img = null; 
    Context mContext;

    public MyOverLay(Context context,GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode) // GeoPoint is a int. (6E) 
    { 
        this.gp1 = gp1; 
        this.gp2 = gp2; 
        this.mode = mode; 
        this.mContext = context;
        defaultColor = 999; // no defaultColor 

    } 

    public MyOverLay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode, int defaultColor) 
    { 
        this.gp1 = gp1; 
        this.gp2 = gp2; 
        this.mode = mode; 
        this.defaultColor = defaultColor; 
    } 
    public void setText(String t) 
    { 
        this.text = t; 
    } 
    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) 
    { 
        this.img = bitmap; 
    } 
    public int getMode() 
    { 
        return mode; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean draw 
    (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) 
    { 
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection(); 
        if (shadow == false) 
        { 
            Paint paint = new Paint(); 
            paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
            Point point = new Point(); 
            projection.toPixels(gp1, point); 
            // mode=1&#65306;start 
            if(mode==1) 
            { 
                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor);                
                // start point
            } 
            // mode=2&#65306;path 
            else if(mode==2) 
            { 
                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor); 
                Point point2 = new Point(); 
                projection.toPixels(gp2, point2); 
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5); 
                paint.setAlpha(120); 
                canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint); 

            } 
            /* mode=3&#65306;end */ 
            else if(mode==3) 
            { 
                /* the last path */ 

                if(defaultColor==999) 
                    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
                else 
                    paint.setColor(defaultColor); 
                Point point2 = new Point(); 
                projection.toPixels(gp2, point2); 
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5); 
                paint.setAlpha(120); 
                canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint); 
                /* end point */

            } 
        } 
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Please don't use comments for status updates. Answers are meant to answer questions as is. If you need extended discussion, do it in chat.

Comment: @ BoltClock's a Unicorn   sure