# Android Google map Kml parsing not working

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I was using Google KML file and parse it to get path on the Google map.

Everything worked fine. But suddenly it stops working.

I've read somewhere that Google has stopped its service for KML.

Just want to know anyone else aware of this fact?

And if Google has really stopped its services for KML file and xml or Json are the only options?

Secondly if yes then can anyone please suggest me how can i move my code from kml to xml or json

Many thanks

Comment: KML service has ended. Question has already been ask a few times already on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer by the same order you posted your questions:

- Yes that's right, KML is not supported anymore.
- XML and JSON are two options supported by the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponses), (not sure if there are more options).
- For **code examples** in how to migrate from KML to XML or to JSON you may want to read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323500/google-maps-api-version-difference).

Answer (score 0):

KML is working currently but its limits of kml , json, xml. 1000  times per day use kml getdata. you can use kml and get data 1000 times per day only..i thing its problem is in code

Google still support KML, to get a KML track or route, use driving instructions as usual, then save to my places. Then you can save the trip. Ther eis a small KML tag next to your trip which allows you to download a route in KML.

Comment: Then what do think why it stoped working suddenly if it still works. My access is less then 100 per day

Comment: This is incorrect. The KML output from maps.google.com was never a documented service. It has been shut off.

Comment: Do you think you or someone could spread that news?  There is [an issue report regarding this](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4321) which could be changed to an enhancement request if there was any official news from Google.  This is the only comment I have seen anywhere about what happened to this functionality. It would have been useful if this had been publicized right away.

Comment: That makes me so sad that KML was shut off. I used to create custom cycling routes in google maps, open the KML in google earth and look at the elevation profile for the route. Is there some other way to open a google maps route in google earth?