# Draw certain routes in google maps with JSON in android

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I want to draw a bus route with Google maps in Android 2.2 and I drew a route with this example [Google Maps API Version difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323500/google-maps-api-version-difference/11357351#11357351) , but route is not exactly as should be. It goes through some streets where it shouldn't go. I hope that you understand me. :) I'm new in this so **I just want to draw a route that goes through certain streets**, where should bus to go, but I don't know how to do it.. Is there any example in which I could figure out how to do this? **Is this possible?**

Edit: Waypoints sure helped for problem above. But is it possible to draw more routes on same map with multiple JSON requests and how to do that? I  want to draw a few bus routes through the city but only know to draw just one. I tried to add another String Url with new JSON request, but it doesn't work that way....

Comment: Can anyone help me with multiple routes on google map in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) to enforce that route pass through those waypoints.
If you don't want Google Map API to render the path for you.