# Route not respect the street in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that gets the current position and the user selects a destination, these two starting locations, it queries Google:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

And get an xml with the places where I "turn" to reach the destination

After I read the xml, and trace a path between first and second point of the xml, and so on

Before the change of API, the path was perfect in the streets, but now appears like this image:

[image]

The code I use to draw:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();

    Point ponto1, ponto2;
    Path caminho = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
        ponto1 = proj.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), null);
        ponto2 = proj.toPixels(geoPoints.get(i + 1), null);

        caminho.moveTo(ponto2.x, ponto2.y);
        caminho.lineTo(ponto1.x,ponto1.y);

        canvas.drawPath(caminho, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you,
I wrote an extensive answer for someone who had the same issue as you.
Check it out, hope it would help you too

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11357351/975959

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I looked for one month, and the problem I think was also what you said about the decode. Now I'll just try to change the mode for the XML I use. Thank you