# google maps route between 2 points in KML format

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, routes

I'm an Android app developer. I have an app that is using google maps api and is getting a route between 2 points from google in KML format. I'we made it using [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations). Everything worked grait until Friday, 27th of July. Now instead of giving the KML file Google is returning HTML web page which contains map with drawn route...

My question is about does anybody know how can I get the KML file now from google or other service like it?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken

Comment: You can see this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to change your implementation.
The way that people used to draw a path on the map to show direction was not official.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/