# Android: Draw route on map using KML file

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-polyline

I have a KML file which is created from [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com). And i want to draw a route on google map.
I am using mapV_2 in my project. Also one more thing I read couple of threds here on SO saying that KML is no more working on google map [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845790/how-do-i-draw-a-kml-file-on-a-mapview-in-android), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723660/android-can-not-get-kml-file-to-parse-and-then-draw-route-on-map). So is it really not working today for Android? Any othe way to get this done?

Comment: Why not working? i already worked with KML.

Comment: Hello, have you seen the link that i have shared in question? they say KML is not supported now. Can you help me with this?