# Getting KML map api response as java script source

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, kml

I  have called this url [http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=60012&     daddr=500+NORTHWEST+HWY,+CARY,+IL,+60013&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml&sensor=false](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=60012&daddr=500+NORTHWEST+HWY,+CARY,+IL,+60013&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml&sensor=false) instead of getting **KML** response I am getting it as **full javascript source**. I am really confused with that. Could any one help me out from this issue.

Comment: well, you do have the string `"&0"` in there, which is almost certainly wrong (it's supposed to be &key=value), but even if you remove that, it still doesn't seem to give you kml

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of extracting the Google Directions from Google by parsing the KML file is no longer available since 27 July 2012 (because Google has changed the structure of retrieving Google Directions, now you can only get it by JSON or XML), it is time to migrate your code to JSON instead of KML.

See the answer (for Android, but I guess you can work it out for BlackBerry) in my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123).