# Google Maps waypoint update

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps output=kml broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken)

I want to use route system by using the coordinate system as:

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=39.951217,32.835406&daddr=39.908288,32.776308&sll=39.951217,32.835406&dirflg=w&hl=en&ie=UTF8&z=14&output=kml

but google has made an update on July 27 and I guess I have to use this format:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

Is there a way to use the old system because I don't think by giving the address I will get a precise result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way of extracting the Google Directions from Google by parsing the KML file is no longer available since 27 July 2012 (because Google has changed the structure of retrieving Google Directions, now you can only get it by JSON or XML), it is time to migrate your code to JSON instead of KML.

Note that origin and destination parameters can be as Latitude & Longitude without the need of using waypoints.

See the answer in my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745316/1230123).