# GIS - Google Map eturn error. It didn't return KML file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to get the KML file from googlemap. I didn't return it. This is my code of getting KML.

```
  public String[] getPathString(String saddr, String daddr){
     String [] result = {"",""};
      try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(
            "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="+saddr+"&daddr="+daddr+"&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&z=20&output=kml");
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output;
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            urlString.append(output);
            urlString.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(urlString);


        String coordinatestring  = urlString.toString().split("<LineString>")[1].split("<coordinates>")[1].split("</coordinates>")[0];
        //System.out.println(coordinatestring);
        String []  coordinates = coordinatestring.split(",0.000000 ");
        //String lineString = "LINESTRING(";
        String lineString =  "";
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length-1; i++){
            lineString += coordinates[i].replace(',', ' ')+",";
        }
        if (lineString.length() > 0)
        lineString = lineString.substring(0,lineString.length()-1);
        //lineString += ")";
        //   );
        System.out.println(lineString);
        result [0] = lineString;

        String ditanceString = "";
        if (urlString.toString().length() > 200)
        ditanceString = urlString.toString().split("Distance:")[1].split("&#")[0];

        result[1]  = ditanceString;


        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        //return result;

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return result; 
    }
```

This is sample URL : 
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=6.87988,79.8906&daddr=6.87991,79.8911&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&z=20&output=kml

But this give like this:

```
    </script> <script type="text/javascript">window.onunload = function(){GUnload();};</script> <script type="text/javascript">window.onresize = function(){resizeApp();};</script>     <style>.msie
e('inlineMarkersContainer').style.display = 'block';function constructEventQueue(queue,handler){return {q:queue,h:handler
}
}
function addDocListener(eventName,fn){if (document.addEventListener){document.addEventListener(eventName,fn,false);}else if (document.attachEvent){document.attachEvent("on" + eventName,fn);}


}
function removeDocListener(eventName,fn){if (document.removeEventListener){document.removeEventListener(eventName,fn,false);}else if (document.detachEvent){document.detachEvent("on" + eventName,fn);}


}





window.gEventQueue = (function(){





function getJsactionNodeForQueuing_(e){var node = e.srcElement || e.target;
if (node.nodeType == 3)node = node.parentNode;


var isMac = /Macintosh/.test(navigator.userAgent);var modified = (isMac && e.metaKey ||
!isMac && e.ctrlKey);
var re = modified ?/^click(modified)?:/ :
/^[^:]*$|^click(plain)?:/;



while (node){var attr = (node.getAttribute &&
node.getAttribute('jsaction'));if (attr){for (var i = 0,actions = attr.split(';');i < actions.length;i++){if (re.test(actions[i])){return node;}
}
}
node = node.parentNode;}
return null;}


var queue = [];

function handler(e){var node = getJsactionNodeForQueuing_(e);if (!node)return;

e.replayTimeStamp = (new Date).getTime();
e.stopPropagation ?e.stopPropagation():(e.cancelBubble = true);
if (node.tagName == 'A' && e.type == 'click'){e.preventDefault ?e.preventDefault():(e.returnValue = false);}

var copy = {};for (var i in e){copy[i]= e[i];}
queue.push(copy);}

addDocListener('click',handler);

return constructEventQueue(queue,handler);}());(function(){var init_timeout=5000;setTimeout(function(){
vpLoad.arg(0,'ait').check();},init_timeout);})();(function(){var main_js_before_onload=true;var not_fully_inlined=true;window.jsLoadCallback = function(appOptions){vpLoad.arg(3,appOptions).check();if (main_js_before_onload){


vpLoad.arg(0,'aij1').check();}
if (not_fully_inlined){

..................


gEventQueue = null;}
function onLoadHideLoadMessage(){}
function onLoadMainJs(){}
function onLoadApplicationInitialize(){
vpLoad.arg(0,'aiol').check();}
function onLoad(){onLoadHideLoadMessage();onLoadMainJs();onLoadApplicationInitialize();}

vpLoad.func(function(sourceTick,vPage,stateBox,appOptions,isHomeVPage){
vpLoad.func(null);loadApplication(vPage,stateBox,appOptions,isHomeVPage);}).check();window.onload = onLoad;

var userActions = [
'mousedown','keydown','mousewheel',
'DOMMouseScroll' 
];var gUserAction = false;function firstActionLoadMessages(){}
function firstActionLoadApplication(){setTimeout(function(){vpLoad.arg(0,'aiua').check();},0);}
function onFirstUserAction(event){for (var i = 0;i < userActions.length;++i){removeDocListener(userActions[i],onFirstUserAction);}
if (gUserAction)return;gUserAction = true;firstActionLoadMessages();firstActionLoadApplication();}

for (var i = 0;i < userActions.length;++i){addDocListener(userActions[i],onFirstUserAction);}
(function(){var cityblock_enabled=true;

if (navigator.geolocation){var inline_compass_size = 90;

var zoomTop = 29 + inline_compass_size;var zoomHeight = 377;e('flmc_inline').style.height = '' + zoomHeight + 'px';e('flmczoom_inline').style.top = '' + zoomTop + 'px';if (cityblock_enabled){
var cbTop = 27 + inline_compass_size;var cbTopPx = '' + cbTop + 'px';var launchpad = e('cb_inl_launchpad');if (launchpad){launchpad.style.top = cbTopPx;}



var pegman = e('pegman_inline');if (pegman){pegman.style.top = cbTopPx;}
}

d1('my_location_button');}
})();</script>  <div></div>  </body> </html>
```

Please anybody help me what is an issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken

Answer (score 1):

This way of extracting the Google Directions from Google by parsing the KML file is no longer available since 27 July 2012 (because Google has changed the structure of retrieving Google Directions, now you can only get it by JSON or XML).