# Drawing path in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an application where I have to draw the path from one point to the other.
Earlier I was using KML for this,and everything was working fine but then KML stopped working.
I am now having only google directions api for this purpose i.e,

```
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=chandigarh&destination=mohali&sensor=false
```

Now what I am doing is drawing path between every two points which this service is returning.
But the problem is, this service only gives a certain number of coordinates.So the path is not perfect.
So my question is, is there any api or service which is more accurate?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your answer,you have to use either xml or json response-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700881/1233606